# Explain this proof of Binet's formula?

Tags: solution-verification, fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

I am confused about the proof offered here: https://sicp-solutions.net/post/sicp-solution-exercise-1-13/.

The proof starts at Fib(*n*) = Fib(*n* - 1) + Fib(*n* - 2), which is true by definition. Then it invokes *a definition we're trying to prove*, namely Fib(*n*) = (*φ<sup>n</sup> - ψ<sup>n</sup>*)/sqrt(5), to infer the next equation. And so on until we infer that *φ<sup>n</sup> - ψ<sup>n</sup>* = *φ<sup>n</sup> - ψ<sup>n</sup>*, "[t]hus proving that Fib(*n*) = (*φ<sup>n</sup> - ψ<sup>n</sup>*)/sqrt(5) is true."

**How does this prove that Fib(*n*) = (*φ<sup>n</sup> - ψ<sup>n</sup>*)/sqrt(5) is true?** (If indeed the proof is valid. If it isn't valid, what would need to be changed to make it so?)

(Is part of the idea behind this presentation that since *φ<sup>n</sup> - ψ<sup>n</sup>* = *φ<sup>n</sup> - ψ<sup>n</sup>* is a tautology, we could have started from there and moved backward to some point? But what point would that be?)

Comment: The wording of the proof may be a bit sloppy, but it is OK. You could make things clear by defining say $G(n)$ to be the expression involving the radicals, and then prove it satisfies three statements, namely the two initial values to start off the recursion, and then the recursive statement. Then conclude it coincides with the Fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This argument is incomplete. What it proves is that $G_n = \frac{\varphi^n - \psi^n}{\sqrt{5}}$ satisfies the same recursion as the Fibonacci numbers. But to prove that it's equal to the Fibonacci numbers you also need to check that it has the same initial conditions

$$G_0 = F_0 = 0, G_1 = F_1 = 1.$$

Fortunately this is not hard.

Comment: In any case it's not a very satisfying argument, since it offers no explanation for why this formula exists or why you would have thought to write it down. Other much more satisfying approaches are possible, using matrices or generating functions for example.